# No coverage results in Android Studio when running shared test in KMM project

Tags: kotlin, android-studio, kotlin-multiplatform

When running the `CalculatorTest` in the [KMM basic sample](https://github.com/Kotlin/kmm-basic-sample) with coverage in Android Studio, why do I not get any coverage results?

##### Running the test

[image]

##### Coverage results

[image]

Comment: are you using mac? it runs fine to me

Comment: Yes. I've tested it on macOS, and also Windows and Linux. It doesn't work for me on any platform

Comment: Please open an issue youtrack.jetbrains.com/newIssue

Answer (score 1):

I think there is some bug in Android Studio for KMM.
It run coverage successfully but does not show results in window.

To see reports you can export the results as HTML and open in any browser.

For my project also I was not getting results, but I was able to see by exporting it.
[image]

[image]